# Get original object name from firebase object inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularjs-ng-repeat

I get from firebase an object with the following code:

```
    var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("categories");
                ref.orderByChild("status")
                .equalTo('featured')
                .on('value', function(snap) {
                console.log('Categories in range', snap.val());
                $scope.categories = snap.val();
                })
```

The object I get contains a couple of objects with the data which look like my example here:

[Example Object from firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Be3Tj.png)

The results i use in my template view with ng-repeat.

```
<ul class="list">
    <li ng-repeat="(category_id, category) in categories | toArray | orderBy:'position'">
      <div style="background-image: url({{category.images[0].src}});" ng-click="category_action(category_id)">{{category.name}}
      </div>
    </li>
```

My problem is now that I want to give the original object name back with ng-click. I tried to use the (key, value) solution from angular for ng-repeat but I dont get the original object name back and only a index number like 0,1,2,3 etc.

What I need is the original name like in this example **KU8JfAZRCsPJy9uOMqm**.
If i only get the index number (0,1,2) back how can I know in my controller which object name this was originaly? Like for example $scope.categories.???

Thank you for your help in advance, I did research but found only people with the same problem but no working solution.

PS: I use firebase 3.x and angular 1.x

Comment: category_id should give you the "original name" you are asking for.
https://jsfiddle.net/f24LL8e1/

Comment: you are right! I just tested around with your example and it worked. since my version did not work I kept on checking and figured the problem is the extra filter "toArray" from [angular-toArrayFilter](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter). With this filter in the middle I get only 0,1,2,3 but i did not see this filter also takes the original key and attaches it as property to the object to use it again. Thanks for your help, works great now!